# Why might a Unity button stop working when X position is not 0?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-ui

I'm pretty new to Unity. I have a button that works perfectly in the editor. When I build it and run on Windows or Mac, the button stops working. Other buttons on the same canvas work fine.

If I recreate the button from scratch and then build after each setting, it seems that it stops working when move it - if the X position is 0 it works, otherwise it will not. It still works in the editor at runtime, but when I build it, it stops working.

I'm not sure where to look to see what is happening. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that you are moving the button and not the sprite?

Comment: Same problem on a button that doesn’t have a sprite. Brand new generic button doesn’t work if it isn’t in the center of the screen. But it works fine playing in the editor - it is only when I build it that it stops working.

Comment: More testing ... the buttons work on Windows but not Mac. If I duplicate a working button, relocate it and change the function, then when it is clicked, it triggers the original button.

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't seem right. Can you confirm that the `Raycast Target` is checked on your Button component? It might be that it is off and another object in the scene is preventing you from clicking on it.

Comment: Raycast Target is checked on the button.

Comment: Also, I tried disabling other objects that I thought might be on top - didn't change anything.

Comment: Now I can confirm that the only buttons that work are where the X position is 0. Even on other scenes. I must have really missed something.

Comment: Button is 120x120 pixels. It has an image and button component. It also has an image child object. When PosX is between -80 and 80 the button works. When PosX is <-80 or >80 then it does NOT work.

Comment: Can you check if the image child object is a raycast target? That might be blocking it.

Comment: I created a generic UI button. Changed nothing except PosX and that doesn’t work either. Something wrong with my canvas?